# Displaying a drop down menu using a PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php function that gets a list of authors from a database...I am trying to get this list to display on a drop down menu, so when the user goes to select by Author it shows up as a list of Authors form the data base...I don't want to input the authors manually but I want it to use the function to populate the list..Here is my getAuthors function

```
  <?php
  function getAuthors($db, $isbn)
 {
 $query = 'SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM books_authors
 INNER JOIN authors ON authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id
 WHERE isbn = :isbn
 ORDER BY author_ordinal';
  $statement = $db->prepare($query);
 $statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);
$statement->execute();
 $authors = $statement->fetchAll();
 $statement->closeCursor();
  $authorString = "";
 $count = 1;
  foreach ($authors as $author)
 {
 $authorString = $authorString . $author['first_name'] . ' ' .   $author        ['last_name'];
if ($count < $statement->rowCount())
  $authorString = $authorString . ", ";
 $count++;
 }
 return $authorString;
  }
  ?>
```

and here is my drop down menu

```
<select name ="searchtype">
            <option value="author"> By author: </option>
```

Comment: This has been asked (and answered) so many times already. Did you really search for an answer? Take a look at the "Related" topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(stcmp($ishtml,"yes")== 0)
{ ?>
    <select name ="searchtype">
                <option value="author"> By author: </option>
    <? } foreach ($authors as $author)
         {
         $authorString = $authorString . $author['first_name'] . ' ' .   $author        ['last_name'];
        if ($count < $statement->rowCount())
          $authorString = $authorString . ", ";
         $count++;
if(stcmp($ishtml,"yes")== 0)
{
        ?>  <option value="<? echo $authorString; ?>"> <? echo $authorString; ?> </option>
        <?
}
         }
```

Just change your foreach code with mine and it should work, you can add a default parameter to function to ask for displaying html code or not.

Change your function header with this:

```
function getAuthors($db, $isbn,$ishtml="no")
 {
... code below
}
```

So now to get the print of the dropdown you need to call your function with a additional parameter of "yes". Thats it